# How to get data in object without looping

Tags: javascript

I want to get data from the object without for loop

this is my object

```
data = [{name:"A",value:[java:45,c++:50]},{name:"B",value:[java:12,c++:47]},{name:"C",value:[java:15,c++:32]}]
```

Expected result:

```
result_name = ["A","B","C"]
result_java = [45,12,15]
```

Comment: array map will do the trick - once you have a valid object of course - as it is, the contents of the inner array are not valid javascript syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- The structure of your array `data` is invalid. You wrote nested array `value` in square brackets yet the items are written as key-value pairs.
- There is no magical way you can obtain multiple data from an array without iteration/looping. (unless you already know the indices, but this defeats the purpose of using arrays)

That said, if you meant to avoid only the "for" loops, you can:

1. Fix your data as below.

```
let data = [
  {name:"A", value:{java:45,"c++":50}},
  {name:"B", value:{java:12,"c++":47}},
  {name:"C", value:{java:15,"c++":32}}
];
```

2. Run an alternative loop such as below.

```
 console.log(data.map(item => item.name)); // ["A", "B", "C"]
 console.log(data.map(item => item.value.java)); // [45,12,15]
```